# Moment.js pluralisation of hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs, intl

Is it possible to make a plural form of *hour* and *hours* through [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)? Or maybe something native from [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

I looking for something like this, because I need localization as well.

```
moment.specialFunction({hours: 1}); // 1 hour
moment.specialFunction({hours: 2}); // 2 hours
moment.locale("ru").specialFunction({hours: 1}); // 1 час
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat):

```js
console.log(
  Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { style: 'unit', unit: 'hour', unitDisplay: 'long' }).format(12),
  Intl.NumberFormat('ru', { style: 'unit', unit: 'hour', unitDisplay: 'long' }).format(12),
  Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'unit', unit: 'hour', unitDisplay: 'long' }).format(1),
  Intl.NumberFormat('ru', { style: 'unit', unit: 'hour', unitDisplay: 'long' }).format(1),
)
```